# Looking at some new tags

Tags: discussion

There a few tags that I find questionable:

[vertices](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vertices)
What purpose does this tag serve? I can't think of any question that this tag could be applied to. Even the only [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/102030/how-can-i-mask-this-canvasrenderer) that uses it has nothing explicitly to do with vertices.

[ecs](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecs)
Is also only used on one [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/101877/collision-response-in-entity-components-systems). Looks like it should be made synonymous with[entity-system](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entity-system)

[crashes](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crashes)
Seems quite ambiguous. If people have problems with software or a bug in their game that causes crashes would [debugging](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/debugging) not be more suitable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed all three tags. I didn't create any synonyms.